# Seeking a User Role Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication

A client of ours is currently using [Rolescoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) as a WP plugin to manage users' access to various "private" pages and posts. However, Rolescoper hides posts/pages from view unless the user is logged in. We're looking for a plugin that shows all the posts/pages but shows a "access denied" message with a prompt to log-in afterwards.

Here's a list of the requests verbatim:

> 1. Create User Account: username/password
> 2. Assign user to a page that is private
> 3. I want the private page to still appear in the navigation, even though a user may not be logged in.
> 4. Once a private page is clicked, they are prompted to enter their username/password. Once they do, they are then redirected to that page.
> 5. This would also need to be applied to document uploads

Any ideas? I did some Googling/WP plugin searching without much luck.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get an answer you like here on SO, you might want to try your question over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it existed. I'll let it marinate here for a bit to see if there's anything before cross-posting it around the interblags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rather than using a plugin, try reworking your template to use [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)?

Comment: That would work globally for users logged in, but we need specific pages to be restricted to specific users/usergroups.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but for anyone else who finds it, I'll take a swing.

You could add to the beginning of your `while` statement in your `single.php` file a "Private" category check and "User Logged In" check, like so (NOTE: redirects to login page if user not logged in and category on post is set to "private"):

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if(in_category("private")){

            if(is_user_logged_in()){

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            } else {

                auth_redirect();

            }

        } else {

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        }
```

[Is User Logged In?](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)

[In Category X?](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/)

See also: [`auth_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect)

Hope this helps!